# What is a sufficient sample size to establish whether difference in mean is significant

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size

I'm very new to the world of statistics.

Could someone explain to me in layman's terms the following:

I have complete data on a population size of ~37,000. I can show, across the entire population, that there are trends between certain variables and the amount of debt (e.g. age, length of tenure etc).

What I'm trying to do is to establish whether there is a statistically significant variation in the effect of these independent variables on debt between geographical location.

Partitioning the data into geographical location results in sample sizes of between 300 and 3000 records. Again dividing these data into age ranges e.g. 25 to 35, 36 to 45 years old etc further reduces the size of each sample.

I've produced a number of graphs using seaborn/matplotlib e.g. regression/scatter plots, grouped column graphs and the results fluctuate especially with smaller sample sizes (e.g. smaller geographical locations).

What I'm trying to establish is is there a statistical test I can carry out that indicates whether a change between geographical location (e.g. average debt for 25 to 35 year olds between location A and B) is statistically significant or due to random error introduced by the size of an individual sample.

I hope that makes sense. Any advice would be gratefully received.

Many thanks

Comment: A statistical test helps you generalize from a sample to the corresponding population or data generating process (DGP). Since you have the entire population, what are you trying to generalize to? Perhaps a superpopulation which your population is an element of, or a DGP which has generated your population?

Comment: Hi Richard. Thanks for your reply. So if I for example had 2 geographical locations A and B. The average debt for people in age range category 25 to 35 years old in location A is much higher than the average debt for people in the same age range category in location B. I want to be able to say with a certain degree of confidence that the difference between the average debt between those two samples is an artefact of an underlying factor (yet to be revealed by further analysis) and not a consequence of the sample size within that location. I want to quantify that degree of confidence.

Comment: OK, so it looks like you are interested in the superpopulation or the DGP. Then the fact that you have an entire population does not matter and you can proceed as if you had a sample.

Comment: Thanks again Richard. So how would I explain the differences in for average debt between locations if say the entire population average debt is \$600 but location A average debt is \$1,500? Location A has a small number of entries compared to the other locations B, C, D etc. Therefore deviations from the average debt in this location are disproportionately affected by outliers compared to other locations with much larger numbers of entries. Baring in mind that boundaries of location can't be changed. Cheers,

Comment: Sorry, I do not have an answer. I just wanted to clarify some details so that the question becomes easier to answer for someone else.

Comment: Try to build a regression model?

Comment: Quickcalcs from Graphpad could be just what you need at https://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/ - You probably should do ANOVA if you want to compare multiple samples or T-tests for pairs of samples.  With regard to outliers, it is worth excluding results that are logically or physically impossible, but otherwise there is no safe way of excluding them.